# Listing posts by grouping dates

Tags: query

I have a music events site http://www.zarpa.eu.
I'm using the Future is Now plugin to help me to schedule the events http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-future-is-now/

I'm trying to group events by dates, something like this: http://pt.yeaaaah.com/pt/agenda-de-concertos

Is there a simple solution for this? I tried many things and I searched for all over Google and nothing..

Thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the following plugin for Event management, and it has short code to display all events and sort them by date. It also has some developer features to give you a bit more control over things.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager/

Very cool plugin that is actively developed.